# Laravel 4.1 - calling View Composers class - ReflectionException class does not exist

Tags: laravel

I keep getting this error when trying to call a View Composer class:  Class MyApp/Composers/HeaderComposer does not exist

/app/MyApp/Composers/HeaderComposer.php:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Composers;

class HeaderComposer {

    public function compose($view) {

        $view->with('foo', 'foobar');

    }
}
```

composer.json:

```
    "psr-4": {
        "MyApp\\" : "app/MyApp/"
    }
```

routes.php:

```
View::composer('layouts.default', 'MyApp/Composers/HeaderComposer');
```

vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
'MyApp\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/MyApp'),
'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
);
```

What else could I be missing?

Thanks,

Ham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change forward slashes in

```
View::composer('layouts.default', 'MyApp/Composers/HeaderComposer');
```

to back slashes

```
View::composer('layouts.default', 'MyApp\Composers\HeaderComposer');
```

and it will work